# Styling a button in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble styling the button.

My precise problem is that I cannot seem to reach the button which is inside the two divs.

HTML:

```
<div id= "nav">
   <div id= "search">
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" required>
        <a href="Linkpage.html"><input type= "button" value= "Search"></a>
      </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #inforight
    {
      width: 200px;
      float: right;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #735D41;
    }
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L44pN/)

Could someone please help?

Comment: Where is the element having `id="inforight"`?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You **cannot** have a button inside a link. Browser error recovery from that error is variable. Don't do that.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: @quentin Thank you and sorry. I'm a total newbie at this and am learning as I go on. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs should be unique. If you have more than one such button on the page (and it seems you have), use classes.

In each case, you need to assign an ID or a class to the button.

Also, you need to fix your HTML. Remove that anchor and set it to form action instead.

HTML

```
<div id="search">
  <form action="Linkpage.html">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" required />
    <input type= "button" value="Search" class="inforight" />
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inforight
{
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #735D41;
 }
```

---

Here's a quick fix of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/L44pN/1/

Comment: Thank you @Shomz. Could you please check my code now? Why is the button so far away from the text box? Sorry in advance if that's a silly question but I'm trying to get the basic idea.  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L44pN/6/)

Comment: You're welcome! No worries, everybody was taking the first steps at some point. :) Your button is far right because you added the right float rule to it. Remove the float, and it will be right next to the input field: http://jsfiddle.net/L44pN/8/

Answer (score 0):

Set the `id` of the button to `inforight` for the CSS to work.

```
<input type= "button" value= "Search" id="inforight">
```

---

Also, you have a button placed inside an `<a>`. If you want to go to *Linkpage.html* on the click of the button, you could set the action page of the form to *Linkpage.html*, and make the button a `submit` button.

```
  <form action="Linkpage.html">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" required>
    <input type= "submit" value= "Search" id="inforight">
  </form>
```

Comment: Than you @John Bupit. Your explanation was very easy to understand.